# Modify a specific column of a specific row in a CSV file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that contains a translation of different labels. Now I want to edit or add a certain value in the ElementsButtonDelete row of a specific column.

```
name                    en_GB   de_DE
ElementsButtonAbort     Abort   Abbrechen
ElementsButtonConfirm   Confirm Bestätigen
ElementsButtonDelete    Delete  Löschen
ElementsButtonEdit      Edit    Ändern
```

let's say I add another word in the ElementsButtonDelete row and I want to add its translation in the ONLY the 4th COLUMN. Is there a way to do that in PYTHON3?

Comment: Yes there is, but please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

use append

```
df = df.append({'Name' : 'value' , 'en_GB' : 'value'} , ignore_index=True)
```